# A (cron) job to run if file has changed

Tags: centos, backup, cron, centos8, sqlite

I need to backup a live sqlite db by running a command once a day. Only **if the db file has changed** since last backup. How could it be achieved on Centos 8 ?

Comment: i missing the things you've already done and what youve been using, more over it looks to me not business related question . a cronjob that runs daily with no specific time can be started by `@daily command` using `crontab - e`

Comment: why is it voted to close? how is it a cron script not part of server admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `touch` command has the ability to set a file's times to be the same as another file.
The BASH shell can `test` to see if one file is newer than another `[ a -nt b ]`.
What you can do then is

- Set a reference file's times to be the same as your db file times using touch.

Then have a script run once per day that checks if the db file is newer than the reference file.

- If it is newer then update the reference file's times to be the same as the db file and backup the db file.
- Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: 2 lines script would bring a lot more information than 7 lines of natural language explanation :D

Comment: Doing it correctly is likely more than 2 lines. If I wrote the script for you, then you are not educated.

Comment: :) bummer innit

Comment: Depends on your attitude to learning I guess. I would find it a most excellent challenge :)